# I'm really confused about Chrome Extension+Google API

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I'm really confused. I want to make a Chrome Extension that can update a user's Google Calendar, what kind of program should I register under Google API?

Is it Web App? But I don't plan to have a server to host anything because Chrome Extensions are in the browser itself.
I really don't think it's a service account, but if it is, somebody enlighten me!
So that leaves installed applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Google Extensions and Google API are very different in nature, and they don't have a special way to comunicate themselves.

Chrome Extensions are javascript code running in the browser allowed by a Chrome user, with more rights than a normal page; while Google API is accessed by server code, just as Google Apps Scripts (javascript code running in a Google server with some Google user's right).